# Can I create mobile native application using jQuery only?

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile

I am beginner in developing mobile applications. I have goggled but not found relevant information. 
I want know that, Is jquery can develop native mobile application? 
Please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. You can build a web based application using straight HTML and JavaScript but the inclusion of jQuery and jQuery Mobile will allow you to more easily style your application in a mobile friendly way. You can also include a manifest and even build an HTML application that will work off-line, but none of this will make it native.

To produce a native-ish application that can be downloaded and installed via one of the app stores, you will need to wrap your web pages in a native framework, the most popular of which is Adobe's [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

PhoneGap will also allow you to directly access a number of native API points on your mobile device that are not typically accessible from within straight HTML and JavaScript.